# Only tab view and button text loading in Simulator/iPhone, but app working in preview

Tags: swift, swiftui

The app works great in preview but when I run it in the simulator for iPhone 11s or on my actual iPhone X only a few things load, and most stuff is blank white. I attached photos to show what it looks like and what it should look like. Anyone ever seen this issue before or have an idea of what it might be?

- [What it looks like, Page 1] https://i.stack.imgur.com/GhbwA.png
- [What it should look like Page] https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQtXm.png
- [What it looks like Page 2] https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1z3x.png
- [What it should look like Page 2] https://i.stack.imgur.com/kiJHJ.png

P.S. I'm super new to SwiftUI, so if it was something super stupid I'm sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Issue 1**:
Your phone is in Dark mode while your Previews are in Light mode. It's hard to say what effect that is having, since you haven't included any code.

**Issue 2**:
Again, because you haven't shown any code, it's tough to say why the background isn't showing up. My suspicion is that it's an image and you have it in your Preview assets, but not being copied to your actual app bundle.

If it's a gradient that is defined in code, you may have colors defined for Light mode but not dark mode.

First thing I'd try is switching your phone to Light mode. Then, make sure that your background image (if there is one) is included in your app's assets.

Comment: Thank you so much, it was in fact that I was in dark mode. I set it up to ignore light and dark mode for now, so the problem went away